Estimating Normal Distribution Probabilities for $n\sigma$ Event in Head
During a joke-around with friends, the question came up - what's the chance of someone being born with IQ $0$? Is it likely that such a person has ever existed in human history?
Ignoring the obvious neurological and scientific answers to this question, which would suggest that a normal distribution is not an accurate model for such large deviations (and what does an IQ of $0$ even really mean, is that even feasibly plausible?), we know that IQ is by definition normally distributed with $\mu = 100$ and $\sigma = 15$. An IQ of $0$ would be equivalent to about a $7 \sigma$ event, maybe a bit less.
It got me thinking, for a standard normal distribution, how could I approximate the probability of an $n \sigma$ event in my head (i.e. the probability that a standard random normal deviate does not fall within $\pm n$, i.e $1-P(-n<X<n)$ for $X \sim \mathcal{N} (0,1)$)?
I know the "68, 95, 99.7 rule" but what if I wanted to know the probability of an event for $\sigma>3$?
The precise number is of minimal importance, more so a good estimate of the logarithm of the quantity, i.e the probability of that happening is about one in ten to the $\ldots$
There's a table for this on Wikipedia (end of this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule) but without that or a calculator what is the best method? Obviously numerical intergation techniques for $e^{-x^2}$ or series expansions of erf(x) are not practical mental techniques.
